# JavaScript Code not working to check radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do validation to check when a radio button is not selected, if it is not selected then a alert should be displayed, but the code below is not working. When the button is pressed thats when validation should happen

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form >
<input type="radio" id="b">
<input type="radio">

<button onClick="checkValidation()" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</form>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkValidation(){
 if (document.getElementById('b').checked == false) {
 window.alert("sometext");
  }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Brackets are not closed properly. Please correct that one first

Answer (score 1):

missing } :

```
function checkValidation(){
 if (document.getElementById('b').checked == false) {
  window.alert("sometext");
 }
}
```

or remove { after the if :

```
function checkValidation(){
 if (document.getElementById('b').checked == false)
  window.alert("sometext");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains error, a missing closing semicolon, `}`, it should be:

```
function checkValidation(){
 if (document.getElementById('b').checked == false) {
 window.alert("sometext");
  }
} //This one is missing
```